# Modal only displays one person - php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, modal-dialog

I made a “popup” dialog when a picture is clicked on. The dialog code is bolded here. In my HTML code I would have to change “openModal” each time to openModal2, openModal3, etc. for each person. Any ideas on how it would work here?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM person2";

if ($result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql)) {    
    // loop through the data
    //create 4 columns for the table
    $columns=4;
    $i = 0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        // the % operator gives the remainder of a division of two values
        // in this case, 0/4, this tells the table row to jump to a new row
        // if there are already 4 columns in one row
        if($i % $columns == 0){

                   //begin table row
                   echo "<tr>";
        }

         echo '<td class="staffImage badgeText frameImage displayInLine">
                <a href=#openModal><img src="images/staff/'.$row["imgName"].'.jpg"></a><br> 
                <strong>'.$row["firstName"].'</strong>
                <strong>'.$row["lastName"].'</strong><br>
                **<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
                    <div>
                               <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
                               <h2>' . $row["firstName"] .
                               $row["lastName"].'</h2><br>
                               <img class="floatLeft" src="images/staff/'.$row["imgName"] .'.jpg">
                               <p><strong>Hire Date:</strong>'.$row["hireDate"].'<br>
                               <p><strong>Major:</strong>'.$row["major"];

                                          //if the field "major2" (Double Major) is not null, display it
                             if($row["major2"] != NULL)
                             {
                               echo ' & '.$row["major2"].'<br>';
                             }

                             //if the field "minor" is not null, display it
                             if($row["minor"] != NULL)
                             {
                               echo '<br> Minor: '.$row["minor"].'<br>';
                             }

                                           //if the field "concentration" is not null, display it 
                             if($row["concentration"] != NULL)
                             {
                               echo '<br> Concentration: '.$row["concentration"].'<br>';
                             }

                    '</div>
                </div>
                <br><strong>'.$row["firstName"].'</strong>
                </div> ';**
            //end <td>       
        echo '</td>';
```

Comment: well that is because you are creating a modalDialog inside your loop.. just create one modalDialog and pass values to it, instead of creating multiple and unnecessary modals.

Comment: create the modal dialog in a separate page?? Sorry I am new at this and don't know much of anything yet :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with your current approach, you have modal inside while loop and modal id `openModal` is repeating, id's must be unique through out the document and to open correct modal, just assign the row `id` to both, modal trigger and modal itself

Modal trigger link

```
<a href="#openModal'.$row["rowid"].'"><img src="images/staff/'.$row["imgName"].'.jpg"></a>
```

and modal

```
<div id="openModal'.$row["rowid"].'" class="modalDialog"></div>
```

Footnote: change value of `$row["rowid"]` to correct col name according to table.

Alternate way is via Ajax method, which you can find many examples on google or search on SO.

Comment: That worked PERFECTLY! I knew I needed personID in there somewhere but could not figure out where! thank you so much!